# Cannot connect proxy_server localhost:3000 to nginx config file (docker-compose project)

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, localhost

I have the following docker-compose.yml files located in two different folders:

`~/front/docker-compose.yml` and
`~/api/docker-compose.yml`

I need to connect proxy_server localhost:3000 (from frontend) to nginx config file (from api). What could I be missing?

Here is the ngix config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.html;
server_name localhost;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/html/public;

}


server {
listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
server_name     client.localhost;    # setup your domain here


 location / {


    proxy_redirect                      off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000/; # set the address of the Node.js instance here
}
}
```

When I do `docker-compose logs -f nginx`, this is the error:

```
2020/08/07 10:50:10 [error] 28#28: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.16.1, server: client.localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "client.localhost", referrer: "http://client.localhost/"
```

[error after running docker-compose logs -f nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIK2s.jpg)

Here is the **front/docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - client_esl
networks:
  client_esl:
   external:
      name : nginx_esl
```

**api/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.5"

networks:
  esl:

services:
  site:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - esl
```

**Dockfile on front folder**

FROM node:12.4-alpine

RUN `mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app`

RUN `WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app`

RUN `apk update && apk upgrade`

RUN `apk add git`

COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/

RUN `npm install`

RUN `npm run build`

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0

ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

Comment: You need to assemble them together in the same docker network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect 2 containers together, there are several options:

- Expose the port to the host as you did (3000:3000), then you can use this port + host IP (not localhost as it refer to the container itself) from the other containers
- Don't expose the port, if the containers are in same network use container name + port like client:3000

Answer (score 0):

run the containers on the same network and on your Nginx config use  `proxy_pass : client:3000` since your container name for your node app is client